# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS on opening Stack Overflow

Tags: support

When I access Stack Overflow by the URL `www.stackoverflow.com` on Chrome I get the following error: `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` although, when I access through Google (question URL or homepage link from Google) for example there's no problem. The problem occurs also on Microsoft Edge.

Someone has this problem or know how to solve?

**Fiddler and additional data**

I'm trying to access from Brazil. When I request the homepage Fiddler shows something like 15 requests then the error on browser.

Headers request:

> GET https://stackoverflow.com/ HTTP/1.1 
>  Host: stackoverflow.com
>   
>  Connection: keep-alive 
>  Cache-Control: max-age=0 
>   Accept:
>   
> text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
>   Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1 
>  User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT
>   10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.130 Safari/537.36 
>  Accept-Encoding: gzip,
>   deflate, sdch 
>  Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,pt;q=0.6 
>   Cookie: prov=1cbd5b0d-fa3c-4ce8-81d7-d8cb97545bca;
>   __qca=P0-1869337894-1430601740241; __cfduid=d04ebde75a7f231d6725121ac549252881436833729; _ga=GA1.2.1050740778.1430601740; acct=t=2sVq9TBNjZfdApXSkC%2flyOLJv7JKwJz0&s=U0Wwsk20l32vnkmNDe4q21MHBWfZdGR0

Headers response:

> HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently 
>  Date: Sun, 09 Aug 2015 19:42:19
>   GMT 
>  Connection: Keep-Alive 
>  Content-Type: text/html;
>   charset=UTF-8 
>  Transfer-Encoding: chunked 
>  Cf-Railgun:
>   5fa2f73714 stream 0.000000 0210 4701 
>  Location:
>   https://stackoverflow.com/ 
>  Server: cloudflare-nginx 
>   CF-RAY: 2135f187d6a70fe2-GRU

@NickCraver [link](http://teststackoverflow.com/headers):

> Headers:
>    Connection: close
>    Accept:
>   
> text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
>   Accept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
>    Host:
>   teststackoverflow.com
>    Referer:
>   [ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS on open stackoverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302086/err-too-many-redirects-on-open-stackoverflow?noredirect=1)
>   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36
>   (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.130 Safari/537.36
>   Cf-Cip-Tag: 456cd2deb4c0c6b35efd551ba18e78749d3a7a1a
>   Cf-Connecting-Ip: 131.100.70.254
>    Cf-Ipcountry: BR
>   Cf-Origin-Https: off
>    Cf-Railgun: 048f0a3b8f 0000 origin
>   4701
>    Cf-Ray: 213b42635568101e-GRU
>    Cf-Visitor:
>   {"scheme":"http"}
>    Cf-Visitor-Port: 80
>   Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
>    X-Forwarded-For: 131.100.70.254,
>   192.124.132.9
>    X-Load-Balancer: co-lb04
>  Query String:
>  Form:

Comment: Use Fiddler and figure out if there is something obviously wrong... If not at least you'll be able to provide more useful details in your post.

Comment: Don't use www in front of stackoverflow.com. That was never needed. As CloudFlare is now between you and the real servers there are known corner cases that lead to strange effects, some caused by cloudflare, this could be one of them.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I updated the question. Thanks.

Comment: @rene I tried without www, the same problem happens

Comment: Ok, the 301 status is there because there was an issue with google results that use port 8080...but that should only be the respons if you're not already at port 80... let me find the info I have seen about this...

Comment: This is the post from Nick I was talking about: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/262272/158100

Comment: Can you try `https://stackoverflow.com`?

Comment: and without the last '/' please.

Comment: yes, I can with https

Comment: it works with http only, the problem is only with www ou stackoverflow.com wihtout http

Comment: Ok, so `https://stackoverflow.com` does work?

Comment: Yes it does, but right now I got error 502 - website is offline, but I'm pretty sure it worked before. I will hold on. During the week I try again

Comment: Hey there, can you try hitting this page for me and update with the output please? http://teststackoverflow.com/headers

Comment: @NickCraver follow up the edit

Comment: Not sure if [this report is related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263697/connection-to-stackexchange-sites-failing-intermitently-today#263697) apart from the country ... @NickCraver

Comment: yes this report is related to my issue. I'm accessing from Brazil too. I've been having that error as well.