# SSL error if I click on "Looking for a job" link on the sidebar career section

Tags: bug, status-norepro, stack-overflow-jobs, ssl

As the title says, clicking on "Looking for a job" link will result in SSL error, discussing further with [@Chris Jester‐Young](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/13/chris-jester-young), it turns out that URL have `:80` for `https://`

[image: SSL Error]

Comment: Might be related to the CloudFlare redirect *fix* for non port 80 connections: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302086/err-too-many-redirects-on-open-stackoverflow#comment231638_302086

Comment: I tried it a few times as well, and twice I was redirected to an HTTP link with port 443 hardcoded, which didn't work either. But I can't reproduce that now.

Comment: ditto, I could reproduce once, but can't anymore